# Can i get the name of the json object from same json object in kotlin?

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I tried to update the sharePreference value using json object.
First I create the json object with name, then update the object in sharedPreference.
But, I unable to get the json object name. Please help me.

```
 team1.put("name", "India")
 updateData(team1)

 private fun updateData(data: JSONObject) {
    val sharedPref: SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SharedPref1", 0)
    val editor:SharedPreferences.Editor =  sharedPref.edit()
    editor.putString("JSONObjectName",data.toString()) // How to get the JSONObject name?

}
```

I want to like this, `data.name == team1`.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to your code, you're looking to get the attribute named 'name'. Right ?

You juste have to do this way:

```
private fun updateData(data: JSONObject) {

    val name = data.getString("name")

    val sharedPref: SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("SharedPref1", 0)
    val editor:SharedPreferences.Editor =  sharedPref.edit()

    editor.putString("JSONObjectName", name)
}
```

Don't forget to check if your JSONObject contains an attribute called 'name' before accessing it to avoid crash ;)